# How can I correctly copy a set of objects without referring to the originals or duplicating those referred to multiple times?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I have a `GameState` object. It contains things like players, the players' hands and the cards in them, the state and location of the players' resources, and so on. Pretty much everything connects to at least one other thing - the cards know what hand they're in, the resources know what player they belong to, and so on.

I would like to create a system for telling the player the difference between two `GameState`s. It would compare the states and come back with "if you did this action, these things would change". The simplest way to do this seems to be to duplicate the `GameState` and apply the action to the duplicate, then compare the duplicate with the original.

I've looked around at some implementations for both shallow and deep copying, but I can quickly forsee issues where one object belongs to two different objects. One example is some player tokens; the player has a list of all tokens that are theirs (so for example the player can take stock of where they all are), and the space the tokens are on has a list of all tokens that are on it (so for example if the space is affected by something it can affect all tokens on it). If I do a deep copy then the player and space will be referring to two different copies of the same token; if I do a shallow copy then everything will be referring to the objects as they exist in the original `GameState`. I can't pick one side to always be shallow and the other to always be deep, because maybe the token will be removed from the board and be on no space, or the token will be disassociated from the player and picked up later by another. There may even be cards that target a player when used, so if it's targetting the user, that'll be a circular reference.

Basically, I want to do the first of these three diagrams, but I can't figure out how to avoid the second and third situations.

[image: drawing of what I'd like to achieve compared to what I know how to do]

I suspect there's no easy way to do this in general, but I figure I might as well ask.

I'm using C# in Unity3D, in case that's important.

Comment: Seems like you will have to define the clone logic yourself.  An alternative idea is to create two methods that will Read and Write a GameState object to a Stream.  Then you could just code something like: MemoryStream ms = ...; Write(GateState, ms); GameState clone = Read(ms);  These would also come in useful if you plan on being able to save a GameState to disk.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some mileage out of serialization as a shortcut to cloning.  I often use JSON.NET (NewtonSoft) to perform a similar operation, and as long as your objects aren't too complex, you can usually get by on a basic "serialize then deserialize" procedure.  JSON.NET handles circular references and the like fairly well, by the way.

I think your bigger challenge is going to be showing the "what will happen" information to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Several months ago, I wrote a simple AI for a Othello chess game. I needed to pass different game states for each move to my evaluation functions. What I did was to "clone" only the essential data required for calculations, and pass the "cloned data" to other functions. Inside the functions, I did things more or less the same as you suggested, i.e. simulate the outcome for each move at each state.

I think define a "cloning" strategy by yourself is inevitable. However, you can extract only the useful data out from the original `GameState` instance. Surely the player's name doesn't matter, right?